# Sql query for counting players

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Count of players who have scored within 500 runs of the leader from particular country. For example if from India A scores 1500 runs then how many players have scored more than 1000 runs.

I have run this code but this is not giving me my desired result.

```
select COUNT( [Player ] )as no_of_players,country from [dbo].[Sheet1$]
where runs >=
All (select max(runs)-500 from [dbo].[Sheet1$] group by country )
group by country
```

[image: Below is the image of dataset that I have created]

Comment: I would minimally expect that you would need your subquery to be correlated. Also, why are you using the `ALL` operator?

Comment: "Count of players who have scored within 500 runs" Do you mean players having score 500 or below?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: please provide expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a window function for this

```sql
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS no_of_players,
  country
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      MAX(runs) OVER (PARTITION BY country) AS MaxRuns
    FROM [dbo].[Sheet1$] s1
) s1
WHERE runs >= MaxRuns - 500;
```

> Note that `COUNT(nonNullValue)` is the same as `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(1)`